# Excel VBA code window opened cropped and can't view code

Tags: excel, vba

I had an excel sheet with VBA macro posted into MS TEAMS. User are aware that they will have to open the file in desktop app to run the macro. Lately, users encountered problem where the macros will not run. When I tried to open the VBA code in VBA editor, all I can see are cropped out code windows with no code to view.

Beside this, when I try to view the macro listing under developer tab, the macro listing showed an empty list.

Has anyone experienced this before and knows of a solution to recover the VBA codes and what caused this to happen?

[image: Cropped code window in VBA editor]

Comment: Looks like an issue with the computer or setup. Test if this occurs on other computers too. And test if all files on the computer wher this happens show this effect so you can narrow down in which part the issue actualy is (file or computer).

Comment: Yes this was tested on another user's system and we saw the same issues. I also tried to save the file as a different filename and gotten error messages telling me error in saving file.

Comment: Well looks like the file is corrupted then (use a working backup). Try saving the file as `.xlsb` format. What was the exact error message you got on saving?

Comment: Thanks Peh. The message was "Error was detected while saving 'c:\.....\.xlsm'. Microsoft excel might be able to save the file by repairing or removing some features. To make the repair in new file, click on continue...." So clicking on continue only won;t work as well. I think you are right that the file is corrupted and trying to identify why it got corrupted might be finding needle in haystack...

Answer (score 0):

So after some on-line search, turned out that a simple open and repair can solve the issues. But if anyone understand the cause of this problem, would appreciate if you can share any experience on this. thank you.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repairing-a-corrupted-workbook-7abfc44d-e9bf-4896-8899-bd10ef4d61ab

Comment: The cause of the problem is your file is corrupted. It's broken. This can easily happen with `xlsm`/`xlsx` files. Save your file in the binary `xlsb` format which is more stable against file corruption.

Comment: Cool. i have not explored and considered this before. Been trying it for a while and seemed to work. Thanks for the suggestions.